# Product detail page custome code Volusion

Tags: product, volusion

http://jrgat.usgdm.servertrust.com/product_p/pagani-huayra-brushed.htm

in this page I want product display look like given link example. product detail would be accordion tab. can anybody help me that how can I do this in volusion ?

http://jrgat.usgdm.servertrust.com/v/vspfiles/templates/240/images/productdisplay.jpg

Comment: Please try to add a set of smaller *images* which represents the issue and which is sufficient to explain what you like to accomplish. Referencing (complex) web sites isn't really a good idea since they can change or vanish at any time.

Comment: thanks for your advice. I have change image. can you check again?